# Last occurence of comma in python dataframe

Tags: python

please help me on replace comma with & in the last occurence of comma

DF['MSG'] =

0                         20.00, 20.00
1                     4.00, 3.00, 2.00
2                               100.00
3                  10.00, 70.00, 10.00
4    10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00
5                                99.00
6                         50.00, 50.00
7                                70.00
8                  10.00, 20.00, 65.00

output is:

0                         20.00, 20.00
1                     4.00, 3.00& 2.00
2                               100.00
3                  10.00, 70.00& 10.00
4    10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00& 10.00
5                                99.00
6                         50.00, 50.00
7                                70.00
8                  10.00, 20.00& 65.00

if the comma occurences are more than 2 then expected in above output in dataframe
plese help me

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried

Comment: i tried this on s['M'] = s['M'].str.replace(',','&',1)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your output doesn't quite match up to what you want since there are two & when there should only be one (namely before the 65.00).  Please explain carefully what it is you want and include the code you've tried with.

Comment: `s` is a pandas dataframe? If yes, please edit your post and copy the output of `s.head()`

Comment: 0                         20.00, 20.00
1                     4.00, 3.00, 2.00
2                               100.00
3                  10.00, 70.00, 10.00
4    10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00
5                                99.00
6                         50.00, 50.00
7                                70.00
8                  10.00, 20.00, 65.00

Comment: please help me it is urgent

Comment: Hi! In order to get a quality answer you have to put more effort in writing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a clean list of numbers, you can change it to a string like this:

```
list_of_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(', '.join([str(i) for i in list_of_numbers[:-1]]) + f" & {list_of_numbers[-1]}")
```

gives

1, 2, 3 & 4